# Machine Learning model to identify grammatical errors in a sentence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics

Is there any machine learning model for identifying grammatical errors in a sentence? Please note that I've already tried BERT which is a classification based model and it is useful to tell us whether a sentence has any errors or not. But what I want is that a model which could identify exactly which word in sentence violates SVA (Subject Verb Agreement) or which causes error in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just tried testing this repo [GECToR](https://github.com/grammarly/gector) it was able to spot the grammatical errors in a sentence and identifying SVA errors were also there.

And building a sequence tagger model can also help you, as described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.12592).